# How do you find text wrapped in `#` or pound signs or hash-tags in the middle of a line of text?

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds, tokenize

## Desired Behavior

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| `Loren, here is some #IN#-line #TEXT# ipsum.` | `(IN)(TEXT)` |

---

## A Failed Attempt

### `(?:?<!^)(?:^\s*)(#\s*[^\n\r]+\s*#+)(?:?<!$)`

> - `(?:?<!^)` ... non-capturing group for anything other than start-of-line
>
>   - `(` ... begin group
>   - `?:` ... indicated that the group should not capture anything
>   - `?<!` ... negative look-behind.
>   - `^` ... start of string or something like a line-break `\n\r?|\r?\n`
>   - `)` ... end of group.
> - `(?:^\s*)` do not capture start of line or zero or more white space chars
> - `(#\s*[^\n\r]+\s*#+)`
>
>   - `(` begin capturing group
>   - `#` exactly one pound sign, number sign, or hash-tag
>   - `\s*`
>
>     - `\s` white-space, like tabs, and carriage returns, et cetra...
>     - `*` zero or more. **(0, +∞)**
>   - `[^\n\r]+` ... anything other than new line or carriage return
>   - `\s*` ... zero or more spaces where space is `\s`
>   - `#+` ... one or more of `#`
>   - `)` ... end of group.
> - `(?:?<!$)` non-capturing group for anything other than start of line
>
>   - `(` ... begin group
>   - `?:` ... indicate that the group should be non-capturing.
>   - `?<!` ... negative look-behind.
>   - `$` ... end of string or something like a line-break `\n\r?|\r?\n`
>   - `)` ... end of group

Comment: What's wrong with `(?<=#)[^#\r\n]+(?=#)`

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?!^)#([^#\r\n]*)#', text, re.M)` is what you probably want. Or `r'(?!^)#([^#\s]*)#'`

Answer (score 1):

You might first match what you want to "get out of the way", and then use an alternation with a capture group for what you want to keep:

```
^[^\S\r\n]*#|#([^\r\n#]+)#(?![^\S\r\n]*$)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of the string
- `[^\S\r\n]*#` Match optional whitspace chars without newlines followed by `#`
- `|` Or
- `#` Match literally
- `([^\r\n#]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than a newline or `#`
- `#` Match literally
- `(?![^\S\r\n]*$)` Negative lookahead, assert not whitespace chars to the right followed by the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v6ipzA/1)

Note that the match if from # to the next #, and will only match TEXT1 in this string `#TEXT1#TEXT2#`

If an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is supported:

```
(?<!^[^\S\r\n]*)#([^\r\n#]+)#(?![\r\n]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZOunt/1)